# Safe to use extensions longer then 3 chars?

Tags: file, operating-system, filesystems, file-extension

I remember there used to be 8.3 file names where you thus had to have a filename no longer than 11 chars with file extension, and thus an extension of 3 chars.
So my question is, I know that the 8 part is not the case any more, but is it still better to use extensions with 3 or less character? Or can I just safely make my extensions longer without worrying about Linux/Mac/Windows(>XP ofc.) with its filesystems complaining? And are there actually filesystems that still use the 8.3 type of files?

Thanks!

Comment: You can nowadays do what you want. But, an extension must be short. Otherwise it's distracting. So if you use 4 or five chars it's fine. Otherwise it is not an extension in my subjective view.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes I was thinking about extensions 4-6 characters long, so extensions are easely recognisable for my program, and don't interfere with other programs extension names.